# What is an observation model?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

What is observation model in Bayesian statistics? Wiki contains no such definition. I know what Sttistical model is. Is observation model the same thing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly, the observation model designates the expression that relates the parameters of the model to the observations. Sometimes, the term is used in conjonction with those of dynamic model. Let me give you the  typical example of an hidden states model:

Consider a time-dependent variable $X_t$ (that is unknown and is typically the target of the inference) handled by the **dynamic model**:
$$
X_t = f(X_{t-1})+\epsilon_t.
$$
where e.g. $\epsilon_t \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $f$ is any function.

Then, the system is observed through an **observation model**:
$$ 
Y_t = h(X_t)+\epsilon^{'}_t
$$
where e.g. $\epsilon^{'}_t \sim N(0,\sigma^{'2})$ and $h$ is any function.